# How can I improve the efficiency of matrix multiplication in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have written a code to do matrix multiplication of different range but it takes a lot of time to exexcute the code,

code:

## Program to multiply two matrices using nested loops

```
import time

print("Enter the size of matrix A")
m = int(input())
n = int(input())
print("Enter the size of matrix A")
p = int(input())
q = int(input())
if(n==p):
     print('enter matrix A')
else:
    print("invalid entry")
    exit()
our_list1 = []
A = []
i = 0
int(i)

for i in range(m):
    for i in range(n):
            number = int(input('Please enter a element '))
            our_list1.append(number)
    A.append(our_list1)
    our_list1= []
print(A)
print('enter matrix B')
our_list1 = []
B = []

for i in range(p):
    for i in range(q):
            number = int(input('Please enter a element '))
            our_list1.append(number)
    B.append(our_list1)
    our_list1= []
print(B)
start_time = time.time()

#
our_list1 = []
R = []

for i in range(m):
    for i in range(q):
            number = 0
            our_list1.append(number)
    R.append(our_list1)
    our_list1= []
print(R)
for i in range(len(A)):

    # iterating by coloum by B
    for j in range(len(B[0])):

        # iterating by rows of B
        for k in range(len(B)):
            R[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
print(R)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

It takes more time to execute this method of matrix multiplication, how can I choose the efficient way of matrix multiplication of huge dimension range? So higher dimension array can be executed smoothly and quickly.
Sample output:

```
Matrix A[[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
Matrix B[[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
[[27, 27, 27], [27, 27, 27], [27, 27, 27]]
--- 0.00014400482177734375 seconds ---
```

it takes 0.00014400482177734375 seconds can I improve this timmings  when I do for  higher dimension multiplication?

Comment: Just use specialized module to do this, namely `numpy`.

Comment: I don't think 0.0001 seconds is "a lot of time" but you should use numpy if you need to do stuff with big matrices

Comment: Okay, I never used numpy before, can I do higher order matrix multiplication with that?

Comment: You can, this module was designed to handle this kind of problem efficiently.

Comment: okay, I'll do with nympy and check the time difference

Comment: import numpy as np                                                                             res = np.dot(A,B)
print(res)

Comment: [[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]][[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
[[27 27 27]
 [27 27 27]
 [27 27 27]]
--- 0.0005307197570800781 seconds ---

Comment: It took me a little bit more than  explicit for loop method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This timings in your comments have some significant drawbacks:

1. `print()` is comparatively expensive and has nothing to do with the calculation. Including it in the timings could take up a big chunk of the overall time.
2. Using wallclock (`time.time()`) is not a good way of getting stable timings; you get one run and anything could be happening on your system.

This should give a better test case for comparison:

```
import numpy as np

def python_lists():
    A = [[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
    B = [[3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3], [3, 3, 3]]
    our_list1 = []
    R = []

    for i in range(3):
        for i in range(3):
                number = 0
                our_list1.append(number)
        R.append(our_list1)
        our_list1= []

    for i in range(len(A)):

        # iterating by coloum by B
        for j in range(len(B[0])):

            # iterating by rows of B
            for k in range(len(B)):
                R[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]


def numpy_array():
    A = np.full((3, 3), 3)
    B = np.full((3, 3), 3)
    result = np.dot(A, B)
```

And the timings:

```
%timeit python_lists()
15 µs ± 45.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit numpy_array()
5.57 µs ± 44.7 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So, NumPy is ~3 times faster for this example. But this would be more significant if you had bigger arrays.

EDIT:
And actually, you could argue that creating `A` and `B` inside the function is not helpful for timing the actual matrix multiplication, so if I instead create the lists/arrays first and pass them, the new timings are:

```
%timeit python_lists(A, B)
14.4 µs ± 98.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%timeit numpy_array(A, B)
1.2 µs ± 13.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

And, for the sake of completeness, for an array with shape (200, 200):

```
%timeit python_lists()
6.99 s ± 128 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit numpy_array()
5.77 ms ± 43.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: thank you for detail analysis, now I'm figuring out to create a function where I can just pass the A and B

Comment: how did you calculate the timing of function %timeit python_lists(A, B)?, if I use that in a code or terminal I get a syntax error

Comment: @NikhilR I use Spyder as my IDE, so it gives me access to iPython magic methods - [`%timeit` is one of those](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-timeit). If you're using regular Python then you will have to jump through some more hoops with the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)